# Precache file with Javascript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

How can I do this:

1. the page loads
2. javascript loads a remote PDF file into local memory
3. the user clicks a button/link
4. the system launches the PDF reader or starts a download dialog with the PDF file already in memory

In other words, it's a regular file download in the browser EXCEPT that the file has already been loading in the background in order to speed up its receipt when/if the user decides to download the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to encode the file (perhaps via a servlet), then you could get it through an XHR, and write it into a data uri, which you could then attach to a button or link.

This technique would probably only work on small files and very recent browsers.

StackOverflow won't let me post an example link as a link, so to test the concept, you'll have to copy the following line into an html file and see if you can load the link:

```
<a href="data:application/pdf;base64,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">pdf link</a>
```

This worked perfectly in Chrome when I tested it just now, and worked partially in Firefox. It didn't work at all in my version of IE.

Another potential solution is to make absolutely sure that the pdf is being cached, and then try to load it in a hidden iframe.  Whether this works or not will depend on how the user has their browser set up.

You should consider not doing it at all, given the difficulties.